# Kiel traduki „now that“ al Esperanto?

Tags: translation

En [unu el la novaĵoj](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1770123604/amikumu-the-app-to-use-languages-with-people-near/posts/1729202) pri [Amikumu](https://www.amikumu.com/eo/) en [Kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1770123604/amikumu-the-app-to-use-languages-with-people-near/description), Richard Delamore (Evildea) skribas en la angla (ekstrakto):

> *Now that we have reached our Events stretch goal, we…*

kaj poste la saman en Esperanto:

> *Nun, ke ni atingis nian streban celon Eventoj, ni…*

Sed ĉi tio ne ŝanjas ĝusta al mi. Mi serĉis *„nun ke“* kaj *„nun, ke“* en Tekstaro, sed ne trovis ekzemplojn, kiuj uzas ĉi tiun esprimon kun la angla senco.

Ĉu mi pravas? Kaj kiel oni traduku tion? En la bulgara, mi uzus esprimon, simila al la sekvaj:

> *Nun, kiam…*
>
> *Nun, post kiam…*

Ĉu ĉi tiuj esprimoj estas ĝustaj? Ĉu oni povas esprimi la saman alie?

Answer (score 1):

The PMEG article on *nun* includes examples with both *nun ke* and *nun kiam*.

http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/tempaj/nun.html

You could also use a participle:

- *Atiginte nian streban celon ...*

Note that the reasons you weren't finding any hits in the Tekstaro is that you need to include a real comma in your search.

Comment: What is a „real“ comma?

Comment: I just posted a new question with answer where I explain.